# Modificador protected o getter java

Tags: java, herencia

me encuentro desarrollando un proyecto en el cual se incluye herencia y quiero cumplir la encapsulación y tengo una duda, que es la siguiente

Tengo una clase padre y luego 3 clases hijas. Para acceder desde las clases hijas a los atributos de la clase padre ¿Qué es más recomendable para no romper la encapsulación y aplicar de manera correcta la herencia? ¿Poner protected los modificadores de los atributos de la clase padre o acceder a los atributos de la clase padre a través de los getters y setters?

Todo con el fin de no romper encapsulación y aplicar de manera correcta herencia.

Un saludo y muchas gracias por vuestro tiempo

Answer (score 1):

En primer lugar, muchas de estas cuestiones de diseño son a veces un poco nebulosas. El programa no deja de funcionar porque uses un sistema u otro, todo lo que pasa es que se hace un poco más difícil de mantener (que no es que no sea importante, pero es más difícil evaluar el impacto de una opción u otra).

La regla del pulgar es separar lo más posible la implementación del contrato, y hacer que las clases sean lo más independiente posibles de los detalles internos de implementación de otras clases.

Imagina que tienes en tu clase padre un `protected int edad`, y accedes A) directamente a ese valor desde las subclases o B) invocas `getEdad()` desde las subclases.

Más adelante te das cuenta que lo que tienes que hacer es guardar la fecha de nacimiento y calcular la edad cada vez. En el caso A), tendrás que modificar todas las clases hijas, en el caso B), no.

Comment: Vale, es decir de ambas maneras es correcto y no hago un mal uso de la encapsulación ni de la herencia pero a la larga es más eficiente el uso de private y los getters en proyectos mayores, si no he entendido mal